# Monaca build wont handle phonegap plugins

Tags: cordova, android-manifest, phonegap-plugins, onsen-ui, monaca

So my issue is that when I export my project from monaca, and build it in phonegap, I have no issues with the plugins what so ever. However, when I build in Monaca, the phonegap plugins aren't working. I am new to the Monaca IDE, is there something I may be missing on my manifest or otherwise?

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="" android:versionName="1.0.0" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.solsticeservice.livingword">
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" version="1.3.1"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" version="0.4.6"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" version="0.2.12"/>
    <gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer" version="0.8.2"/>
    <gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" source="plugins.cordova.io"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"/>
  <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="Living Word">
     <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="Living Word" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
</manifest>
```

My WWW/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.solsticeservice.livingword" version="1.0.0">
  <name>Living Word</name>
  <description>Living Word Evangelical Free Church</description>
  <author/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" version="1.3.1"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" version="0.4.6"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" version="0.2.12"/>
  <gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer" version="0.8.2"/>
  <gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" source="plugins.cordova.io"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"/>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG"/>
  <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTop"/>
  <preference name="ErrorUrl" value=""/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="monaca:DisableCookie" value="false"/>
  <feature name="App">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>.............etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Found out it was just the building engine with Monaca, they needed to be imported and installed through their IDE instead of the phonegap method. Which results in paying for the developer plan.